# Could not find method apply() for arguments [7.1.1] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, github, gradle

when i import a project from github to my android studio i have this problem ( problem with gradle )
i need a method how to use old project from github without use internet and download gradle every time

[image: Error like this]

**build.gradle**

```
apply '7.1.1'
android {
compileSdkVersion 32
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "course.labs.fragmentslab"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 32
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

}

**gradle-wrapper.proprties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
```